# How to identify community type using apex controller?

Tags: lightning, lightning-community

I am working on Salesforce community. where I am getting one issue. Here is my issue.

I have configured 2 communities

1. Lightning community
2. Visualforce + tab community

I have one common visual force page for both community which contains one submit button. When user click on that submit button I have to redirect user to some page.

- If Lightning community user click on that submit button I want to redirect to the lightning component.
- If Visualforce + Tab community user click on that submit button I want to redirect to Apex page.

**Note:** I have common Apex controller to prepare URL for the submit button.

**Issue:** How I can identify user have clicked submit button from which community(Lightning community or Visuforce community)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will recommend that you create a separate Lightning Aura Component so that you utilize that in case of Lighting Community and you don't have a dependency on the VF page.

If you cannot, then I would think you can utilize [`$User.UITheme`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_useruitheme.htm) here for the purpose (I haven't tried it myself). You can have this condition checked in your VF page to determine the Theme rendered for VF + Tabs (which will be Classic) vs. Lightning Community and utilize to render different command buttons serving different purpose.

Your submit button's implementation will then look like something as:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!submitForClassic}" value="Submit" 
                    rendered="{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme3'}"/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!submitForLEX}" value="Submit" 
                    rendered="{!$User.UITheme == 'Theme4d'}"/>
```

This way only one of the buttons will be displayed on the VF page and that you can then handle the submit differently based on which one is clicked.

Comment: Thanx man..!!! it worked!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Site.getName()` to get the developer name of the Site you're currently in. See:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm